# DBComparer - Out of bounds when selecting database?

Tags: database, t-sql

I recently got a new computer and installed all of the programs again that I use every day when developing. When I tried using [DBComparer](http://dbcomparer.com/) (that I've used for years with no problems) suddenly I keep getting this error (see picture) over and over when I try to select database.

[image: Picture of error message]

I've read a couple of threads where the answers were only "uninstall" or "use another program".

Solutions I've tried so far:

- Uninstall and install again.
- Tried both x86 and x64.
- Run as admin.
- Switched authentication metod.
- Double checked the authentication (logged in with the same on SSMS17).
- *Edit* Uninstalled SSMS17 and installed SSMS16.

Comment: Have you tried emailing the DBComparer support address, support@dbcomparer.com, shown on their site at http://dbcomparer.com/Support.aspx

Comment: @mc110 My colleague tried it. He said that the support mail inbox was completely full so he couldn't get through.

Comment: How annoying. Looks like they are falling the wrong side of the line discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299

Install SSMS2014. Do it by click download on Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 Express, then scroll down to the bottom and install SQL Server 2014 Management Studio. Then suddenly DBComparer started working again.

Comment: It does not make any sense that downloading SSMS will make DBComparer work. Did you download 64 bit or 32 bit version of DBComparer?

Comment: @Mukus I can't remember. Probably 64.

Answer (score 0):

Installing SQL Server 2014 developer edition worked for me.

The DB Comparer 3.0 needs something that SQL Server 2014 or SSMS 2014 has. It would be nice to know which thing.